# JNI, multiple java classes in a single file

Tags: java, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface, sdl

I'm having a bit of a problem in SDL2 on android, where I can't get the resolution of my window (everything I've tried either returns 0x0 or crashes). So I was trying to work around this by sending the resolution directly from java to c++, unfortunately, every time I try calling my native method, my app crashes.

```
The SDLActivity.java file contains multiple classes.



 public class SDLActivity extends Activity {
 //some code
}
class SDLMain{
//more code
}

class SDLSurface extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, 
    View.OnKeyListener, View.OnTouchListener, SensorEventListener  {
protected static float mWidth, mHeight;

public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder,
                               int format, int width, int height) {
//Code, including code that sets mWidth and mHeight
}
}
```

And a bunch of other classes like that.

Now, in the class SDLSurface, I've been trying to create a native method that sends mWidth and mHeight to my c++ code, unfortunately, every time I call this method, my app crashes.

```
native void passResolution(float w, float h);
```

And in my main.cpp

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_org_libsdl_app_SDL_SDLActivity_passResolution(JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz, jfloat w, jfloat h)
{
    windowWidth = w;
    windowHeight = h;
}
```

I just can't seem to figure out what I did wrong. Does anyone have any ideas?

Exception:`[2014-05-11 14:27:17 - ddms] Can't bind to local 8653 for debugger
[2014-05-11 14:27:18 - ddmlib] De software op uw hostcomputer heeft een verbinding verbroken
java.io.IOException: De software op uw hostcomputer heeft een verbinding verbroken
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.ddmlib.JdwpPacket.writeAndConsume(JdwpPacket.java:213)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Client.sendAndConsume(Client.java:642)
    at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHeap.sendREAQ(HandleHeap.java:348)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Client.requestAllocationStatus(Client.java:488)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.createClient(DeviceMonitor.java:835)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.openClient(DeviceMonitor.java:803)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.deviceClientMonitorLoop(DeviceMonitor.java:621)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.access$100(DeviceMonitor.java:44)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor$3.run(DeviceMonitor.java:580)`

Comment: Crashes how? Exception? SEGV? Core dump?

Comment: An exception. I've just added it.

Comment: According to the method signature the native method is in SDLSurface, not SDLActivity. Did you move it after running javah? I'm not clear what your title has to do with the question either.

Comment: I'm not even using javah.
But I did move it and change the name several times trying to get it to work. Eventually, I did manage to solve my original problem in a different way.

Comment: Did you try [SDL_GetWindowSize](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetWindowSize) ? If that does not work (after SDL initialization), then it's a bug.

Comment: Perhaps the data structure [DisplayInfo](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/native/+/jb-dev/include/ui/DisplayInfo.h#28) should work ? You can try getting it like [this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/88238/how-do-i-get-an-android-devices-screen-size-in-exact-pixels/#142399) . Also your exception doesn't appear to be from your code but rather than from the DDMS. Can you post the logcat stack trace ? Also don't meddle with the javah headers. Your JNI function signature is different from what you mention.